# How to use Java variables in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins job which run auto tests on server and send result to email in html formt.
HTML report page copied to ftp using comands

`robocopy \\%vm%\TEST_AT\AT-Tool_%build% .\TA\ *.html *.version /NFL /R:1
robocopy "\\%vm%\TEST_AT\AT-Tool_%build%\report" "\\ftp\ftp\Projects\TA\CI-results\cd%drop%_patch\%BUILD_NUMBER%" /E`

HTML report contains links to png images like:

```
file://ftp/ftp/Projects/TA/CI-results/cd14_patch/185/detailed_report_2-TC__dataset1/pages/screenshots/screen-thread-24-1420740565855.png
```

HTML report is generated by Java code and images path is a variable

I need to attach this `.png` files in email with HTML report which send my Jenkins job.

Is it possible to improve my Jenkins job for sending email with such attachments?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a post build step in Jenkins witch will create a ZIP archive.

I my project I'm using shell script for it:

```
zip -r ${reports_version}.zip docs source
```

And for e-mail you can use jenkins `e-mail ext plugin`
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

It allows you to attache files to e-mail notifications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are java variables available in  shell script?

Comment: @jhenya-d Hm, no, shell have nothing in common with JAVA :)
As I understood you have test reports that stores in folder \TEST_AT\AT-Tool_%build%

So you can ZIP this folder and attache this archive to email using e-mail ext plugin.

What OS do you have on JENKINS server?

Comment: @jhenya-d than you can use shell script for ZIP the folder, that contains your test report.